# Android Security Application

Tags: android

Is it possible to make the application password protected in Android mobile? ie; if a user tries to install an unauthorized application, we shud prevent that. for tht we will have to make some applications password protected. like "LockMe" in symbian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can either develop your own system if you have your own database you contact it and check.

I'm not sure you can prevent somebody from pushing an app to their phone but you can look into

[preparing app](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/preparing.html)

there are some option like licensing in the android market

Comment: Thanks .. But I want to ask that I am going to develop an android application that can restrict any installation of other application. Is it possible??